# How to add auto triggers in node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, triggers, rest

I want to know how to do auto triggers in node js with mysql database. I don't know the exact word for this type of works. But I can mention what is I am looking for.

Here is the scenario :

***Scenario 1 :***

In the database their is a table called send_email and it has columns id, time and email_address. So I want to send a email to that particular email at that time. How I can achieve this task in node js rest api with mysql database?

***Scenario 2:***

In the database their is a table called send_notification and it has columns id, date and email_address. So I want to send a email before 1 day to that date reminding the user and also after that date.

***Scenario 3:***

Send a email or do some database operation every day at 12.00 a.m.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1 :**

In the database their is a table called send_email and it has columns id, time and email_address. So I want to send a email to that particular email at that time. How I can achieve this task in node js rest api with mysql database?

**Solution**: Suppose you want to send email on every 3rd hour. Create one method which will get data from mysql and send email.

```
let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0 */3 * * *', () => {
   //call method here
});
```

**Scenario 2:**

In the database their is a table called send_notification and it has columns id, date and email_address. So I want to send a email before 1 day to that date reminding the user and also after that date.

Solution: Run cron job every day on specific time and get record from db use these queries.

```
SELECT * FROM FOO
WHERE date >= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
// This query will help to get records 1 day before

SELECT * FROM FOO
WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
// This query will help to get records 1 day after

let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0 0 * * *', () => {
   //call method here
});
```

**Scenario 3:**

Send a email or do some database operation every day at 12.00 a.m.

**Solution**

```
let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0 0 * * *', () => {
   //call method here
});
```

**Nodemailer** is a package which will help to send email

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo ?" <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

or without SMTP

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    transport: 'ses', // loads nodemailer-ses-transport
    accessKeyId: 'AWSACCESSKEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'AWS/Secret/key'
});
transporter.sendMail(data[, callback])
```

Comment: Can you please mention the link for this node-cron module? npm link?

Comment: @shehan96 I am using this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron. In this you can find the full detail of this package.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question. You want to send emails to users on a specific time.

`Nodemailer` is a super cool module for Node.js application to allow email sending so easily.

```
let mailOptions = {
      from: '<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
      to: '<TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
      subject: 'Email from Node-App: A Test Message!',
      text: 'Some content to send'
};
```

You can **SMTP** transporter too.

```
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: '<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
          pass: '<FROM_EMAIL_PASSWORD>'
        }
    });
```

You can schedule these emails, you can use a node module called, `node-cron`.

```
let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  //here your logic for email
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually what I want to know is how to trigger above type of events and do some activities. It can be sending email or something else.

Comment: You can create functions with your implementation and call them inside your cron at given schedule.